# Determining file/folder accessibility in non elevated mode (being elevated)

Tags: windows, elevated-privileges

At install time, running with elevated privileges, I need to know if a specific folder (already existing) will be accessible in non-elvated mode. Anyone know the way to determine the accesibility of a resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/05/26/who-has-access-to-a-folder-c.aspx) is an example of code showing the access rules for a specific folder